# How to change oozie call back command from curl to wget

Tags: oozie

I don't have the linux utility curl installed in my linux system.
How can I change the oozie callback command from curl to wget ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default oozie uses curl as callback command. 
It is possible to change the callback command to wget by overriding 2 properties in oozie-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>oozie.action.ssh.http.command</name>
    <value>wget</value>
</property> 

<property>
    <name>oozie.action.ssh.http.command.post.options</name>
    <value>--post-data #stdout --header "content-type:text/plain"</value>
</property>
```

Just change the above properties in oozie-site.xml and restart oozie server.